# Stream std::any without knowing the type

Tags: c++, c++17

I want to stream `std::any` without actually knowing the value.

I know there is `std::any.type()`, but I am not sure how to use it in `std::any_cast<type>(thatAny)`

This is code I tried:

```
std::cout << std::any_cast<a.type()>(a) << std::endl;
```

Comment: `type()` is a run time value where as template arguments must be compile time constants.

Comment: Classic problem, you need to create a function and check the type, and for each of the relevant types, you call std::any_cast.

Comment: I would say `std::any` is wrong for whatever task you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher: If you had such a type list, why are you using `std::any` instead of `std::variant<...>` ?

Comment: That's true indeed.

Comment: Have you tried std::static_cast<void*>(type) ?  obvious assign to void *

Comment: You may want to consider the boost.type_erasure library. It's made for exactly this purpose. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/boost_typeerasure/basic.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to store how to stream it somewhere.

There are a few different approaches.  If you can centrally enumerate or register all of the types you can stream, you can create a map from typeid to streaming code, then use that map to stream your specific `std::any`.

```
std::unordered_map< std::type_index, void(*)(std::any const&, std::ostream&)> streamers;

template<class T>
void add_streamer() {
  streamers[ typeid(T) ] = [](std::any const& a, std::ostream& os ) {
    os << std::any_cast<T>(a);
  };
}
template<class...Ts>
void add_streamers() {
  ( void(add_streamer<T>()), ... );
}
```

Now you can stream:

```
void stream( std::ostream& os, std::any const& a ) {
  streamers[ a.type() ]( a, os ); // maybe check errors!
}
```

---

An alternative plan is to augment your `any` instances.

```
struct streamable_any : std::any {
  void(*streamer)(std::ostream&, streamable_any const&) = nullptr;
  friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, streamable_any const& a ) {
    a.streamer( os, a );
    return os;
  }
  template<class T,
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>, streamable_any>{}, bool> = true
  >
  streamable_any( T&& t ):
    std::any( std::forward<T>(t) ),
    streamer([](std::ostream& os, streamable_any const& self ) {
      os << std::any_cast<std::decay_t<T>>(self);
    } )
  {}
};
```

now a `streamable_any` now only stores streamable types and store how to stream it in a function pointer with the instance.

A safer `streamable_any` would not publicly inherit from `std::any`, as modifying the `std::any` through conversion-to-base will break streaming.  It is just a pain due to `any_cast` and the like.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4fee084a06e98671).

Comment: What kind of stuff do I need to include? Getting type_index and other kind of errors.

Comment: @Mr.DeleteMyMessages Google "std type index".  Get cppreference page.  Click on it.  Observe at top it states which header it is defined in.

Comment: @Mr.DeleteMyMessages Also, I fixed two typos, and linked a live example of `streamable_any` running.

Comment: @steph no, but it probably says what is wrong in the full error message.  They just take time to decode.

Comment: @steph yes, a `wstreamable_any` is slightly different.

Comment: Also, would you be kind enough to explain what the std::enable_if_t protects against? I cannot seem to be able to trigger it...

Comment: @steph643 That is to avoid it being preferred over the `streamable_any(streamable_any&)` non-const copy-ctor; I want that to dispatch to `streamable_any(streamable_any const&)`, and a few similar cases.

Answer (score 2):

It's not *directly* possible.

However, if you have a `T`, don't store that directly but store `{T, [](T const& t) { using std::to_string; return to_string(t); }}`. I.e. store with each `T` also a lambda that serializes that particular `T`.

Alternatively, you can keep the `std::any` as-is, but wrap it in a custom type and store an appropriate `[](std::any const& a) { return to_string(std::any_cast<T>(a));}` alongside the `std::any`. E.g. if you insert an `int`, you also create and store a `[](std::any const& a) { return to_string(std::any_cast<int>(a));}`